# How to run xp_cmdshell from my app in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, xp-cmdshell

In my app I'm reading data to database and then I want to start Integration Serivces to import the data into the cube. This is the command, which I use to start it from SSMS:

```
execute master..xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /DTS "\MSDB\B_Costs" /SERVER . /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING V'
```

But how use it from my app? I've got this error at the begining:
*The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_cmdshell', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.*

And after use such command:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_cmdshell TO [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool]
```

I've got another error:
*The xp_cmdshell proxy account information cannot be retrieved or is invalid. Verify that the '##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account##' credential exists and contains valid information.*

And as I checked I have no credentials in *Database Engine -> Security -> Credentials*.

I wanted use such command as:

```
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool', 'password'
```

But I don't know what should I write in 'password'. Any suggestions?

This is my CubeController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{            
    string sql = "execute master..xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /DTS \"\\MSDB\\B_Costs\" /SERVER . /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING V'";
    try
    {
        MyEntity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string error = "There was an error: <br />" + e.Message;
        TempData["Message"] = error;
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this link below would be able to assist you. Please let me know if it is working.

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/xpcmdshell-for-non-system-admin-individuals.html

```
After you set up a proxy account your non-sysadmin logins might still not be able to use xp_cmdshell.    If you have not granted your non-sysadmin user EXECUTE permissions on xp_cmdshell you will get this error:

Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 1
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_cmdshell', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
To overcome this error all you have to do is make sure the non-sysadmin user has a database user in the master database and then GRANT your non-sysadmin user the rights to execute xp_cmdshell.  In order to do that all you have to do is run the following TSL code:

USE master;
GO
CREATE USER [MyDomain\Dorothy] FOR LOGIN [MyDomain\Dorothy];
GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_cmdshell TO [MyDomain\Dorothy];
```

In my case, I tried:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_cmdshell TO [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool]
```

I am granting it for

> DefaultAppPool

See the screenshot for your reference:
http://postimg.org/image/yqcf3vya1/

The result is successful. I used either my sa or administrator account to login to my database through SQL Server Management Studio to do the `GRANT EXECUTE`. Please try and let me know the result. Thanks

Comment: I wrote: `CREATE USER [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool] FOR LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool];` and I have error: *User, group, or role 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool' already exists in the current database.*

Comment: Then just run the 
GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_cmdshell TO [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool];

What is the result?

Comment: Oh sorry, I used in my question revoke instead of grant. The error is as above, in question.

Comment: I know about it, just look at my question. "And after use such command: `GRANT EXECUTE ON xp_cmdshell TO [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool]` I've got another error: *The xp_cmdshell proxy account information cannot be retrieved or is invalid...*"
You see? I've done this, but then I've got error associated with proxy.

Comment: Yes, which account did you use to execute that command? SA account or administrator account?

Comment: Always administrator account with Windows Authentication, because I can't login as SA (I've tried reset password, I have enabled SA login and SQL Server and Windows authentication mode).